# Encode sequence of Bitmap images to a video using Android Media Codec and Media Muxer

Tags: android, video, bitmap

I want to encode a series of bitmap images to a video file (mp4) and want to save it on phone. I have gone through Media Codec documentation but unable to understand it completely. I am a beginner in android development. 
Kindly provide me a code snippet to get started with this task.

Best wishes

Comment: You can try Google search for "snippets". Did you try any search **[results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=android+SDK+encode+%22bitmap%22+to+%22video%22)**?. If you want a faster Answer just expand on _"unable to understand it completely"_, so which part of it...? Any other useful info you can share? If you don't show any code we can't help you fix it. For everything else just web search for articles & tutorials. Beginner should understand how bitmap data, bytes & video formats work only then can you try make a video app...

Comment: For instance in understanding the technical details for configuring the encoder. I am using an external camera (not built-in android camera) for my project. So Frame rate for the camera is 9 fps. So in context to it what values should i choose for MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE and I_Interval. Further which color format should i choose to encode video?